# Quit Excel via Script

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I'm trying to quit Excel via AppleScript

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
quit
end tell
```

Unfortunately, when I have a new spreadsheet opened, run the script and select "Do not save" then Excel does close but after a while Automator prompts a Syntax error stating AppleEvent caused a timeout.

Is there a better way to quit Excel avoiding this error?

Thank you!

Comment: If you doing this in automator, would the `quit excel` action not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

I think this small adjustment will avoid any timing out errors.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to quit saving no
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I actually do want to see the prompt which asks me if I want to save progress.